# Pjsip app crashes on pj_thread_register([strName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], a_thread_desc, &a_thread); line

Tags: ios, asterisk, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

2 times I need to register external thread to pjsip. First time when I register thread to call pjsip registration function to register to asterisk server, that registration goes all well and user also gets register to asterisk server.
but when second time I try to register thread to call make_call function of pjsip to make a call, app gets crash on pj_thread_registe line.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to initiate new call you have to check if current thread is already registered before you make a new registration. Your register thread method could look like code below.

```
-(void)registerThread{
    pj_status_t status;
    pj_thread_desc aPJThreadDesc;
    if (!pj_thread_is_registered()) {
        pj_thread_t *pjThread;
        status = pj_thread_register(NULL, aPJThreadDesc, &pjThread);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
            NSString *errorMsg = @"Error registering thread at PJSUA";
            ALog(@"%@", errorMsg);
        }
    }
}
```